# Configure Atheros AR9285 wireless in Gentoo

Tags: networking, wifi, gentoo

My laptop has an Atheros AR9285 wireless card. By following the "Network Configuration" section in the Gentoo handbook I chose the ath9k module. The modules seem to be loaded correctly:

```
# lsmod | grep ath
ath9k                  72172  0 
ath9k_common            2345  1 ath9k
mac80211              146807  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath9k_hw              213153  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                     8652  2 ath9k,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              112782  4 ath9k,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath
```

And the interface also shows up in ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:43:61:a2:f0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

However, I cannot do a network scan:

```
# iwlist wlan0 scanning
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

And the interface doesn't seem to be recognized:

```
# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     no wireless extensions.
```

What can I try to make it work?

PS: I also have Ubuntu on this laptop and wireless is working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution on [Gentoo Forums](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic.php?p=6483150#6507317). It turned out to be a mis-configured kernel.

Here is the kernel configuration that works (from the post that I linked to above):

```
[*] Networking support  --->
    -*-   Wireless  --->
        <*>   cfg80211 - wireless configuration API                                                                                                                  
        [*]     enable powersave by default
        [*]     cfg80211 wireless extensions compatibility
        [*]   Wireless extensions sysfs files
        <*>   Common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
        <*>   Generic IEEE 802.11 Networking Stack (mac80211)
              Default rate control algorithm (Minstrel)  --->
        -*-   Enable LED triggers

Device Drivers  --->
    [*] Network device support  --->
        [*]   Wireless LAN  --->
            <*>   Atheros Wireless Cards  --->
                <*>   Atheros 802.11n wireless cards support
```

Comment: You wanna add exactly which config options you changed?

Comment: @Tshepang the config options is in the post I linked to, do I really have to duplicate it here?

Comment: I'm interested only in the ones you changed --> "when I set this and that option to that and this, the problem got fixed". Don't make me read the whole thread :)

Comment: @Tshepang The working configuration is already on the post I linked to (it is an anchor that links exactly to where the configuration is). Anyway I included that in the answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the anchor. The point is, what were your initial settings? Did you lose them?

Answer (score 1):

If you use DE, it's better to use NetworkManager ([description of configuring NM on Gentoo](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/NetworkManager)).

Otherwise, you need to edit the net configuration file(`/etc/conf.d/net`):

```
config_wlan0=("dhcp")
modules=("iwconfig")
preferred_aps=("WI-FI_NAME")
config_WI-FI_NAME=("dhcp")
```

and then run `/etc/init.d/net.wlan0 start` to start it.

Comment: I don't have a file named `/etc/init.d/net.wlan0`. I guess that's the problem

Comment: Try this: 
cd /etc/init.d
ln -s net.lo net.wlan0

Comment: It tries to work like an Ethernet interface (wait for carrier and time out). Still I am unable to do any scanning.